# Flot: Threshold Failing to Show on Vertical Bar Graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am trying to add thresholds to a vertical bar graph, but for whatever reason, they are failing to appear.

Here are my settings for the graph:

```
var metOptions = {
    series:{
        bars: {
            show: true,
            align: "center",
            barWidth: 24 * 60 * 60 * 600,
            lineWidth: 1,
            fill: 0.7,
        },
    },
    xaxis: {
        mode: "time",
        axisLabel: "Date",
        axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
        axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
        axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
        axisLabelPadding: 10,
        color: "black",
    },
    yaxes: [{
        position: "left",
        min: 90,
        max: 100,
        color: "black",
        tickDecimals: 2,
        axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
        axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
        axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
        axisLabelPadding: 3
    }
    ],
    legend: {
        noColumns: 1,
        labelBoxBorderColor: "#000000",
        position: "ne"
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: true,
        borderWidth: 2,
        mouseActiveRadius: 50,
        backgroundColor: { colors: ["#ffffff", "#EDF5FF"] },
        axisMargin: 20
    },
    tooltip: true,
    tooltipOpts: {
        content: "%x, %y%"
    }
};
```

Here is my dataset definition:

```
var dataset = [
    {
        label: "Metalization",
        data: chartData,
        color: "#F00",
        threshold: [
            {
                below: 95,
                color: "rgb(0, 0, 255)"
            },
            {
                below: 94,
                color: "rgb(0, 255, 0)"
            }
        ],
    }
]

$.plot($("#metal-variance"), dataset, metOptions);
```

And here is the data I am currently testing with:

```
[[1445144400000,95.76],[1445230800000,95.83],[1445317200000,93.99],[1445403600000,94.57],[1445490000000,93.37],[1445576400000,88.53]]
```

With X being a time stamp, and Y being the value.

And here is a screen shot of the graph that is generated:
[Flot Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXCLs.png)

So I have set the thresholds so that if the value is below 94, the bar should be green, but as you can see from the image, the third and fifth bars are below 94, but yet they are still displaying as red.

Any help with this issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s95psbkc/):

[image]

Are you sure you have included the `jquery.flot.threshold.min.js` file?

Comment: Yes, the threshold scripts is being loaded, and I can hit break points in it from this view. Thresholds also working in other views, but it seems that something in this view is just causing it to fail, and I have no idea why.

Comment: Try to build a fiddle that shows your problem, then I could take a look at it. Otherwise I don't see what the cause could be.

Comment: Think I figured it out. I noticed in the fiddle, you were referencing the min file, so I swapped my reference over to that and it worked flawlessly, of course I have no idea why this works, but Ill have time to figure that out later. Thank you for your help @Raidri.

Comment: Which version do of the threshold plugin do you use? My fiddle uses version 1.2.

Comment: That is the one I am using as well